# Where does fopen() search for File to read?

Tags: c, windows, unix, file-io, fopen

I just want to know the **search range** of `fopen()` in :

- a) Windows
- b) Unix-like systems like MacOS & Linux

When asked to open a file for reading, or reading & writing or even just writing, with a relative path, e.g. `File.txt`. And I need an answer addressing both - text & binary files.

Does it scan only the current directory, or does it scan particular folders ?

(Since scanning full disk would be painstakingly slow, right ?)

Comment: If it's an absolute path, then that path is simply used.  For a relative path, in Linux it will be relative to your cwd (current working directory).

Comment: @TomKarzes what about Windows ? Say the user simply asks to read a "Resume.txt" file ?

Comment: Windows has a working directory just like Linux. A relative path is relative to it.

Comment: Fundamentally, `fopen()` does no searching — it opens the named file and only the named file.  If the named file doesn't exist, the open fails.  The name is either absolute or relative, as already stated.  Windows only complicates things by having multiple drives and names prefixed by a drive but not with an absolute name on the drive (`C:filename.txt`) are interpreted relative to the current directory on the specified drive.  I believe, but I'd stand to be corrected, that there can be a different current directory on each drive.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I didn't quite understand. Are you implying that in Windows too, the cwd is looked in ?

Comment: AFAIK Windows maintains a current working directory for each drive. And then there is a current drive, too.

Comment: It depends on the filename passed to `fopen()`.  If the name passed is `filename.txt`, then `fopen()` on Windows will attempt to open one file — and that will be in the current directory of the current drive.  If the name is `subdir\filename.txt`, then it will try to open only one file — and that will be in the subdirectory of the current directory of the current drive.  And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fopen() doesn't scan at all
It just opens the file you tell it to open.
The path is either absolute, or relative to the current directory.
The behaviour is pretty much the same across platforms.

Of course in Windows paths look a bit different (drive letters, backslashes instead of slashes).

One relevant difference I can think of:
If the path starts with a drive letter  and a colon, it will look at another drive.
If there is no backslash after the drive letter and colon, then the location will be relative to that drive's current working directory (as Windows remembers a current directory per drive letter).

Comment: How does it know which file to open without scanning.. I mean it needs to check which file is the filepath referring to right?

Comment: The path specified is either the absolute path or a relative path relative to the current working directory. So that specifies exactly which file, no scanning needed.

Comment: I get what you are saying but my point is like os needs to internally check whether the given name is same a file name right? Like comparing strings you don't know if "test" is "test" until you compare. I hope you get what I am trying to ask.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to understand how the OS organizes filesystem functionality. That's quite low level. Basically you need to understand that the full path name is how the location of a filename is expressed. The OS will parse that into folders and a filename to determine where to find its contents.

Comment: Kind of understood it. Thanks for the quick response